# Dynamic configuration object based on __setattr__ and _getattr__

Tags: python

I tried to create dynamic object to validate my config in fly and present result as object. I tried to achieve this by creating such class:

```
class SubConfig(object):
    def __init__(self, config, key_types):
        self.__config = config
        self.__values = {}
        self.__key_types = key_types

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if item in self.__key_types:
            return self.__values[item] or None
        else:
            raise ValueError("No such item to get from config")

    def __setattr__(self, item, value):
        if self.__config._blocked:
            raise ValueError("Can't change values after service has started")

        if item in self.__key_types:
            if type(value) in self.__key_types[item]:
                self.__values[item] = value
            else:
                raise ValueError("Can't assing value in different type then declared!")
        else:
            raise ValueError("No such item to set in config")
```

SubConfig is wrapper for section in config file. Config has switch to kill possibility to change values after program started (you can change values only on initialization).

The problem is when I setting any value it is getting in infinity loop in getattr. As I read `__getattr__` shouldn't behave like that (first take existing attr, then call `__getattr__`). I was comparing my code with available examples but I can't get a thing.

I noticed that all problems are generated my constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cf ecatmur's answer for the root cause - and remember that `__setattr__` is not symetrical to `__getattr__` - it is unconditionnaly called on each and every attempt to bind an object's attribute. Overriding `__setattr__` is tricky and should not be done if you don't clearly understand the pros and cons.

Now for a simple practical solution to your use case: rewrite your initializer to avoid triggering **setattr** calls:

```
class SubConfig(object):
    def __init__(self, config, key_types):
        self.__dict__.update(
            _SubConfig__config=config,
            _SubConfig__values={},
            _SubConfig__key_types=key_types
            )
```

Note that I renamed your attributes to emulate the name-mangling that happens when using the double leading underscores naming scheme.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your constructor in initialising the object calls `__setattr__`, which then calls `__getattr__` because the `__` private members aren't initialised yet.

There are two ways I can think of to work around this:

One option is to call down to `object.__setattr__` thereby avoiding your `__setattr__` or equivalently use `super(SubConfig, self).__setattr__(...)` in `__init__`.  You could also set values in `self.__dict__` directly.  A problem here is that because you're using double-underscores you'd have to mangle the attribute names manually (so `'__config'` becomes `'_SubConfig__config'`):

```
def __init__(self, config, key_types):
    super(SubConfig, self).__setattr__('_SubConfig__config', config)
    super(SubConfig, self).__setattr__('_SubConfig__values', {})
    super(SubConfig, self).__setattr__('_SubConfig__key_types', key_types)
```

An alternative is to have `__setattr__` detect and pass through access to attribute names that begin with `_` i.e.

```
if item.startswith('_')
    return super(SubConfig, self).__setattr__(item, value)
```

This is more Pythonic in that if someone has a good reason to access your object's internals, you have no reason to try to stop them.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, solution is to change in construtor all setters to: `super(SubConfig, self).__setattr__('__config', config)`. In this way my overwritten `__setattr__`don't work. Also I could add some ifs in setter to pass values starting with double underscore.

Comment: `setattr` won't work because that always encounters `__setattr__` machinery.  See added code above.